# Construct a string parameter to function - powershell

Tags: string, powershell, function

Im wondering how you can construct a string on the fly as a parameter to a function?
Example
say I have a function like

```
function MyFunc
{
    Param
         (
              [Parameter(mandatory=$true)] [string] $myString,
              [Parameter(mandatory=$true)] [int] $myInt
         )

    Write-Host ("Param 1 is {0}" -f $myString)
    Write-Host ("Param 2 is {0}" -f $myInt)


}
```

How can I call it whilst constructing the first string param on the fly e.g.

```
$myName = "Casper"
$myInt=7

MyFunc "Name is " + $myName $myInt
```

Ive tried putting {} around the first "bit" like

```
MyFunc {Name is " + $myName} $myInt
```

This then incorrectly prints out

```
Param 1 is "Name is "+$myName
Param 2 is 7
```

what I want it to print is

```
Param 1 is "Name is Casper"
Param 2 is 7
```

I know a better way of doing this would just be to set up the string first,

```
$pm1 = "Name is " + $myName
```

and call function
MyFunc $pm1 $myInt

but I am just interested to know how it can be done on the fly as it were.  How can I construc the string and pass as first parameter on the function call?  Hope thats clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you can always nest any complex expression in a separate pipeline using the subexpression operator `$(...)` or grouping operator `(...)`:

```
MyCommand $("complex",(Get-Something),"argument","expression" -join '-')
```

But in your particular case we don't need that - you just need to place the variable expression `$myName` inside the string literal and PowerShell will automatically evaluate and expand its value:

```
MyFunc "Name is $myName" $myInt
```

If the variable expression is to be followed by some characters that would otherwise make up a valid part of the variable path, use curly brackets `{}` as qualifiers:

```
MyFunc "Name is ${myName}" $myInt
```

Comment: Thats perfect thanks.  The $() bit is what I needed to know.